# clusterProfiler cannot load package

Tags: bioconductor, patchwork

I am trying to load clusterProfiler, but regardless of how I install the package or whether I un-install or re-install, I continue to get the below error when I attempt to load it. I have also recently installed and loaded patchwork. Appreciate any tips.

```html
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘clusterProfiler’:
 object ‘patchworkGrob’ is not exported by 'namespace:patchwork'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I solved it by loading the library(patchwork) before loading clusterProfiler.

Hope it helps~